# Hibernate, could not execute query, SQL Error: 17059, SQLState: 99999

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

my Query is :

```
@Query(value = "select * from Person where ID=?1 and NAME=?2", nativeQuery = true)
List<Person> getPersonID(Integer id, String name);
```

My log:

```
select
        * 
    from
        Person
    where
        ID=? 
        and NAME=?
2017-10-04 08:43:45.255 TRACE 8860 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [25]
2017-10-04 08:43:45.255 TRACE 8860 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [Julian]


java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.CharCommonAccessor.getInt(CharCommonAccessor.java:123) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CVarcharAccessor.getInt(T4CVarcharAccessor.java:524) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedStatement.getInt(GeneratedStatement.java:217) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedScrollableResultSet.getInt(GeneratedScrollableResultSet.java:573) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedResultSet.getInt(GeneratedResultSet.java:1350) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.IntegerTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(IntegerTypeDescriptor.java:62) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:238) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:234) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:224) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:300) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2727) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1729) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1655) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1544) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:727) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
```

My Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "BIRTHDAY")
    private Date birthday;

    @Column(name = "SIZE")
    private Integer size;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Date getBirthday() {
        return birthday;
    }

    public void setBirthday(Date birthday) {
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }

    public Integer getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(Integer size) {
        this.size = size;
    }
```

if i try my query in the sql developer it works fine.
It seems like my data types are mismatched, but i checked it all, and i all data types are correct.

Has anybody faced the same problem as me and can help? 
Or has anybody an idea what could be the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possibly a driver mismatch? What version of oracle are you using?

Comment: Can you also post your `Person` entity class?

Comment: My version of Oracle is: 11.2.0.4.0

Comment: Try the driver of that version

Comment: You may need to address some of the points in the answers below. But first thing first. Gotta use the driver that works with your version of oracle db

Comment: Check data in DB for two field that is `Integer` and `Date`.
Maybe data stored to database have problems.
Somthing like big number for integer or date format.

Comment: I had this issue too, Moodi is right there is probably a binding mismatch, one field is not bound to the correct type I.E Java Integer <> VARCHAR2 instead of NUMBER in the Orable DataBase.

Answer (score 2):

I would not execute a native query because the `select *` may introduce binding problems. You either have to select each field or as already said use a HQL query.

Comment: For sure this provides an answer: select * may introduce a result binding problem that maybe the name is irregularly bound to the id. That's why he should not use a native query but an HQL query like for instance `select p from Person p where p.id=?1 and p.name=?2`.It is at least worth a try.